# Send IoT Message to Azure Event Hub by URL

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am now using a Beacon Reveiver to get the iBeacon Information. 
Here is the problem:

the receiver platform server only allow me to type a url. 
How should I do to send the information to azure eventhub??
I found this API:

https://NAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net/EVENTHUB-NAME/publishers/PUBLISHER-NAME/messages

I tried it ,but it seems doesn't work.
Do i miss anything?? or Can anyone teach me how to add the authentication in url? What should I do now?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must set an authentication HTTP header in order to send events to Event Hubs. You can't include authentication information in the request URL.

Even though you can't send messages directly to Event Hubs, you can develop a custom Web API that uses your own URL-based authentication mechanism and forwards the requests to Event Hubs (or another service). That defeats the purpose of using Event Hubs to some degree but gives you more flexibility.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain "how" ? I'm trying to send a message with cURL as a POST request but it fails with "Expired Token". I tried `--header "Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=myeventhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net&sig=mySasKey&se=1403736877&skn=RootManageSharedAccessKey"`, replacing myeventhub-ns by my real namespace, and mySasKey by the first key available in the shared access policies menu of my Event Hub**s** namespace. But it always fails with the 401 code: Expired Token. Same key is valid from Java code to send message, so I'm sure my key is OK. Thanks

Comment: @Cheloute are you replacing the `se` parameter value with the correct Unix time?

Comment: Worst, I wasn't using a generated token but directly the event hub shared key. I replaced all the "Authorization" header with the result of `SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider.generateSharedAccessSignature(...)` and now I'm able to send my event thow cURL as expected! Thanks for your help